# Why invoke "apply" instead of calling function directly?

Tags: javascript, splat

When looking at the source code for raphael or g.raphael or other libraries I've noticed the developer does something like this:

```
var val = Math.max.apply(Math, data_array);
```

Why not just invoke the function directly, such as:

```
var val = Math.max(data_array);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Ok so I see that Math.max takes two arguments so my example of just calling, 

    Math.max(array)

wouldn't work. So, I guess the question is how is the first line of code in my question invoking "max" on each element of the data_array?

Comment: Javascript's `.apply` and `.call` ftw!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the explanation from the [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) describes it well:

> You can assign a different *this* object
>   when calling an existing function.
>   *this* refers to the current object, the
>   calling object. With apply, you can
>   write a method once and then inherit
>   it in another object, without having
>   to rewrite the method for the new
>   object.
>
> apply is very similar to call, except
>   for the type of arguments it supports.
>   You can use an arguments array instead
>   of a named set of parameters. With
>   apply, you can use an array literal,
>   for example, fun.apply(this, [name,
>   value]), or an Array object, for
>   example, fun.apply(this, new
>   Array(name, value)).

As for the parameters:

> **thisArg** 
>       Determines the value of *this* inside fun. If *thisArg* is null or
>   undefined, *this* will be the global
>   object. Otherwise, this will be equal
>   to Object(thisArg) (which is thisArg
>   if thisArg is already an object, or a
>   String, Boolean, or Number if thisArg
>   is a primitive value of the
>   corresponding type). Therefore, it is
>   always true that typeof this ==
>   "object" when the function executes.
>
> **argsArray** 
>       An argument array for the object, specifying the arguments with which
>   fun should be called, or null or
>   undefined if no arguments should be
>   provided to the function.

The docs give a good example of a use case for apply. In the example below, apply is used to chain a constructor:

```
function product(name, value)
{
  this.name = name;
  if (value >= 1000)
    this.value = 999;
  else
    this.value = value;
}

function prod_dept(name, value, dept)
{
  this.dept = dept;
  product.apply(this, arguments);
}
prod_dept.prototype = new product();

// since 5 is less than 1000 value is set
var cheese = new prod_dept("feta", 5, "food");

// since 5000 is above 1000, value will be 999
var car = new prod_dept("honda", 5000, "auto");
```

Notice that in the `prod_dept` constructor, the `this` supplied refers to the `prod_dept` object, and `arguments` is an array of arguments passed to the `product` constructor.

Comment: `prod_dept.prototype = new product();` this line is not required at all, please remove complication!

Answer (score 13):

Math.max won't accept a list by default. "apply" allows you to unpack the list to arguments so that max works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Why invoke “apply” instead of calling function directly? Let's have a snippet:

```
var obj = {a: "apply"};
func.call(obj, "parameter");
function func(para) {
    if(this.a === "apply"){
        console.log('apply'); 
     }
}
```

Here we can see we are using `'this'` (context) within a function, If we directly call a func than we don't have any context, than it will take `window` context, which is wrong. So, if you are using context within your function than use `apply` method.

Answer (score 0):

`.apply` is often used when the intention is to invoke a variadic function with a list of argument values, e.g.

The [`Math.max([value1[,value2, ...]])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function returns the largest of zero or more numbers.

```
Math.max(10, 20); // 20
Math.max(-10, -20); // -10
Math.max(-10, 20); // 20
```

The `Math.max()` method doesn't allow you to pass in an array. If you have a list of values of which you need to get the largest, you would normally call this function using [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), e.g.

```
Math.max.apply(null, [10, 20]); // 20
Math.max.apply(null, [-10, -20]); // -10
Math.max.apply(null, [-10, 20]); // 20
```

However, as of the ECMAScript 6 you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

> The spread operator allows an expression to be expanded in places where multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements (for array literals) are expected.

```
Math.max(...[10, 20]); // 20
Math.max(...[-10, -20]); // -10
Math.max(...[-10, 20]); // 20
```

When calling a function using the variadic operator, you can even add additional values, e.g.

```
Math.max(...[10, 20], 50); // 50
Math.max(...[-10, -20], 50); // 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would use `apply()` and `call()` to be able to set the context or the object to which the calling function belongs to. The function then effectively becomes a method of that object/context which is helpful if you'll need to access the fields of the context.

This is how Javascript natively invokes functions:

1. Make an argument list (argList) out of parameters 1 through the end
2. The first parameter is thisValue
3. Invoke the function with this set to thisValue and the argList as its argument list

Reference: [Understanding JavaScript Function Invocation and "this"](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/) by [Yehuda Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/about/)

So, when calling a function directly you are actually implicitly passing in a default context to the function. Javascript passes `'window'` or `'undefined'` as context when you don't specify it using `call()` or `apply()`

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8659422/1075499) also gives an example which might help in understanding the usage