# context to use call and apply in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Guys can any one explain context to use `call` and `apply` methods in Javascript?

Why to use `call` and `apply` instead of calling a function directly ?

Comment: [This read](https://t.co/BVQPwfqqnO) helped me understand the point of `thisArg` when calling `apply()` and `call()` which seems to be the core of your question. You need to understand function invocation primitive in Javascript

Answer (score 83):

You use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) when you want to pass a different `this` value to the function. In essence, this means that you want to execute a function as if it were a method of a particular object. The only difference between the two is that `call` expects parameters separated by commas, while `apply` expects parameters in an array.

An example from [Mozilla's `apply` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), where constructors are chained:

```
function Product(name, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;

    if (price < 0)
        throw RangeError('Cannot create product "' + name + '" with a negative price');
    return this;
}

function Food(name, price) {
    Product.apply(this, arguments);
    this.category = 'food';
}
Food.prototype = new Product();

function Toy(name, price) {
    Product.apply(this, arguments);
    this.category = 'toy';
}
Toy.prototype = new Product();

var cheese = new Food('feta', 5);
var fun = new Toy('robot', 40);
```

What `Product.apply(this, arguments)` does is the following: The `Product` constructor is applied as a function within each of the `Food` and `Toy` constructors, and each of these object instances are being passed as `this`. Thus, each of `Food` and `Toy` now have `this.name` and `this.category` properties.

Comment: just a question about the code snippet provided, why Toy's and Food's prototype gets replaced by a Product object?

Comment: Commenting just to bump @davids question: why do we need to do `Toy.prototype = new Product();`? I tested this and removing those lines seems to make no difference in the end result.

Comment: @davids & @adrianp : It is needed to make Food and Toy inherit from Product. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Shawn/xNEYf/ I removed `Toy.prototype = new Product();` but left `Food.prototype = new Product();` in, so now Food inherits from Product, but Toy does not. I also added a method to Product's prototype and called it from Food and Toy to make the lack of inheritance more obvious (just open the console and run the code, Food can call the method inherited from Product, but Toy cannot and throws an error).

Comment: How would the prototype be used when used with object literals?

Comment: I guess I just don't understand the purpose for doing this instead of something that seems much easier, such as [this](https://repl.it/EDzh).

Comment: @Shawn If you don't add a Product's prototype and remove `Toy.prototype = new Product();` and `Food.prototype = new Product();` it works fine then why add those lines in the example.

Answer (score 23):

Only if you use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) you can modify the `this` context inside the function.

Unlike other languages - in JavaScript `this` does not refer to the current object - rather to the execution context and can be set by the caller.

If you call a function using the `new` keyword `this` will correctly refer to the new object (inside the constructor function)..

But in all other cases - `this` will refer to the global object unless set explicitly through call

Comment: It might refer to the caller obj, if using `obj.whatever();` syntax.

Comment: The statement "But in all other cases - this will refer to the global object unless set explicitly through call" should be corrected to following: "But in all other cases, unless set explicitly through call, this will refer to the global object if using Ecmascript 3 or Ecmascript 5 (or later) in non strict mode. However, in Ecmascript 5 (or later) with strict mode, this is always undefined if not explicitly set and the JS Engine will throw an exception when you access this." Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822561/why-is-this-in-an-anonymous-function-undefined-when-using-strict

Answer (score 12):

You use `.call()` when you want to cause a function to execute with a different `this` value.  It sets the `this` value as specified, sets the arguments as specified and then calls the function.  The difference between `.call()` and just executing the function is the value of the `this` pointer when the function executes.  When you execute the function normally, javascript decides what the `this` pointer will be (usually the global context `window` unless the function is called as a method on an object).  When you use `.call()`, you specify exactly what you want `this` to be set to.

You use `.apply()` when the arguments you want to pass to a function are in an array.  `.apply()` can also cause a function to execute with a specific `this` value.  `.apply()` is most often used when you have an indeterminate number of arguments that are coming from some other source.  It is often used too pass the arguments from one function call to another by using the special local variable `arguments` which contains an array of arguments that were passed to your current function.

I find the MDN references pages for [.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) helpful.

Comment: Thanks, you explain it very well. Finally understand the usage of the first argument.

Answer (score 4):

If you have experience with jQuery, you will know that most functions take use of the `this` object. For example, `collection.each(function() { ... });`
Inside this function, `"this"` refers to the iterator object. This is one possible usage.

I personally have used `.apply()` for implementing a queue of requests - I push an array of arguments into the queue, and when the time comes for executing it, I take an element, and pass it as the arguments for a handler function using `.apply()`, thus making the code cleaner then if having to pass an array of arguments as a first argument. That's another example.

In general, just keep in mind that those ways to call a function exist, and you may one day find them convenient to use for implementing your program.

Answer (score 1):

If you have experience with `Object Oriented Programming` then call and apply will make sense if you compare it with inheritance and override the properties or method/functions of parent class from child class. Which is similar with call in javascript as following:

```
function foo () {
  this.helloworld = "hello from foo"
}
foo.prototype.print = function () {
  console.log(this.helloworld)
}

foo.prototype.main = function () {
  this.print()
}


function bar() {
  this.helloworld = 'hello from bar'
}
// declaring print function to override the previous print
bar.prototype.print = function () {
  console.log(this.helloworld)
}

var iamfoo = new foo()

iamfoo.main() // prints: hello from foo

iamfoo.main.call(new bar()) // override print and prints: hello from bar
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any normal situation where setting the thisArg to something different is the purpose of using apply.

The purpose of apply is to pass an array of value to a function that wants those values as arguments.

It has been superseded in all regular everyday usage by the spread operator.

e.g.

```
// Finding the largest number in an array
`Math.max.apply(null, arr)` becomes `Math.max(...arr)`

// Inserting the values of one array at the start of another
Array.prototype.unshift.apply(arr1, arr2); 
// which becomes 
arr1 = [...arr2, ...arr1]
```