# Javascript difference between calling a function directly and using apply

Tags: javascript

Both are calling the same function and in the same context, then what is the difference between in these statements.

```
this.subject.hello();
```

apply() is used to call the method in the different context. But here it is called in the same context.

```
this.subject.hello.apply(this.subject, arguments)
```

Comment: *apply* doesn't change "context", it is used to set the value of a function's *this* to a particular value.

Answer (score 2):

The first one calls it with no arguments. The second one calls it with arguments of the current function.

```
this.subject = {
  hello: function() {
    console.log("Hello called with arguments " + JSON.stringify(arguments));
  }
};

function callHello() {
  console.log("this.subject.hello();");
  this.subject.hello();
  console.log("this.subject.hello.apply(this.subject, arguments);");
  this.subject.hello.apply(this.subject, arguments);
}

callHello(1, 2);
// => this.subject.hello();
//    Hello called with arguments {}
//    this.subject.hello.apply(this.subject, arguments);
//    Hello called with arguments {"0":1,"1":2}
```

Comment: I can also pass the arguments in the first one.

Comment: In general, you will use `apply` to call functions/methods when you don't know how many arguments you will have. A common example is destructively concatenating an array: `concat` returns a new array, but if you want to concat by modifying an existing array, you'd use `push`: `array.push(3, 4)`. But if you have two arrays, you can't use `array.push(other)`; saying `array.push(other[0], other[1])` is stupid because you need to know it will never have more than 2 members, you cannot use the Ruby splat trick of `array.push(*other)`; so you need to apply `apply`: `array.push.apply(array, other)`

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that in the first call you are not passing in any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

with `apply` we can change context of method, normally it takes the context of current object. context is passed as first parameter is apply method, and other parameters are passed inside a array which is second parameter in apply method.

for other queries between `call` and `apply` you can refer 
[Stackoverflow question : What is the difference between call and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply)

Comment: "*normally it takes the context of current object*". Nope. A function's *this* is set by the call, it's not related to the current (execution) context. Many functions are called without setting *this* so it defaults to the global object or *undefined* in strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that one with `arguments` and other one without.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some great answers on topics of `apply`, `call` and JavaScript context:

- [context to use call and apply in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659390/context-to-use-call-and-apply-in-javascript)
- [What is the difference between call and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply)
- [How does the Math.max.apply() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255138/how-does-the-math-max-apply-work)