# How to understand underscore's invoke

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to understand underscore's `invoke()` function, but I'm having trouble in a few areas. Here's the code from the annotated source:

```
  _.invoke = function(obj, method) {
    var args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
    var isFunc = _.isFunction(method);
    return _.map(obj, function(value) {
      var func = isFunc ? method : value[method];
      return func == null ? func : func.apply(value, args);
    });
  };
```

In this example:

```
_.invoke([[5, 1, 7], [3, 2, 1]], 'sort');
=> [[1, 5, 7], [1, 2, 3]]
```

I understand what is going on; however, in the source code, I don't understand the function of `args`. In what kind of situations would additional arguments need to be used?

I'm also new to programming, and I'm struggling with how `apply` is being used here. I'm guessing it's because I don't fully understand the use of `invoke`, namely the use of `args`. Still, in looking at examples provided in [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), one example used `Math.max.apply(*null*, numbers)`, so why is it being applied to `value` in the source code?

Note: I've read many articles on it including [this](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659390/context-to-use-call-and-apply-in-javascript), and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), and several other videos, but am still struggling.

Comment: [The lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs#invoke) have a better example that might explain it better

Comment: You should be doing `_.invoke(arrOfArrays, 'sort',function(a, b){ return a-b;})`

Answer (score 7):

If you check Underscore `invoke` docs, you see this:

> Calls the method named by `methodName` on each value in the list. *Any extra arguments passed to invoke will be forwarded on to the method invocation*.

You see? All that magic with `apply` and `args` is used so you could fire that method in `invoke` with some arguments.

### Whats the function of `args`?

Take a look at `join` array method - it joins elements into a string, and if we pass something - it would be used as a separator.

```
var things = ['apple', 'banana', 'mango'];

things.join('#') // 'apple#banana#mango'
```

So, `join` can take arguments. Lets use it with `invoke` now.

```
var manyThings = [ 
  ['apple', 'banana', 'mango'],
  ['pepsi', 'fanta', 'sprite'],
  ['bear', 'wolf', 'parrot'] 
];

// Pass '#' as a third argument - is like join('#')
console.log(_.invoke(arr, 'join', '#'));

// ["apple#banana#mango", "pepsi#fanta#sprite", "bear#wolf#parrot"]
```

We passed '#' to that `join` method! That's the situation when we use that additional arguments.

How it works?

```
var args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
```

We store all arguments passed to `invoke`, starting from third (first is a list, second is a method name). We store '#' in our `manyThings` case.

Every `invoke` argument we pass after `methodName` becomes arguments for this `methodName` function.

```
_.invoke(obj, 'methodName', '#', 2, false, '--')
// It's like do obj.methodName('#', 2, false, '--')
```

Function of `args` - to store passed arguments to use it in the method.

### Why we need `apply`?

When we have all that arguments, we are ready to pass them to method we have here:

```
var func = isFunc ? method : value[method];
```

You see? We took `value[method]` function. Somewhere deep inside this function use `this`. So to be able to fire that function on the right object with right `this` (manyThings array), we need `apply`. And we pass `args` as a second parameter to `apply` (in our case it's '#').

This how it works, i hope you have better understanding now.

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation @Alexander.  I am having trouble understanding the 'value[method]' portion of the ternary operator.  Can you expand on this snippet of the code?

Comment: We can pass `methodName` or function. So in ternary we check - if we pass function, use it as is. If we pass not function - like string 'sort', we assume it's a method name, so we pick it from object `value`. And and this object - from current iteration by collection we pass to invoke initially.