# Understanding this JavaScript function overloading example

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm currently studying [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://www.manning.com/resig/) by [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/) and I'm hoping someone can help me further understand one of the examples.

It is a function that allows method overloading on an object, each overload has it's own definition and behaviour.  He blogged about it [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-method-overloading/).

The code looks like this:

```
function addMethod(object, name, fn) {
   var old = object[name];

   object[name] = function(){
      if (fn.length == arguments.length)
         return fn.apply(this, arguments)
      else if (typeof old == 'function')
         return old.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

And used like this:

```
addMethod(obj,'funcName',function(){});
addMethod(obj,'funcName',function(a){});
addMethod(obj,'funcName',function(a,b){});
```

I think I understand most of how this works but you can get a better explanation than I can give from the blog post above).

However, it accesses the value of `old` and `fn` using closures, which I'm still studying.

EDIT - added `jsFiddle` below.

When trying to understand it, I realised that the line return `fn.apply(this, arguments)` could be simply `return fn()` with what seems to be the same result. See an example in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5mWX/1/).

So, Why is it using the `apply` syntax if not required?

I have tried playing with the example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5mWX/1/) without apply and it always seems to wo

Also, what exactly is happening when we return those functions, especially in the case of:

```
return old.apply(this, arguments);
```

I really want to get a solid understanding of not just how to use this method but why it works so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the answers.  I will study them all and accept the best answer - although, that looks as if it may be difficult looking at the high quality of the answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, Why is it using the `apply` syntax if not required?

It is actually required for the usage.

`this` and `arguments` are different for every `function` and are set when they're called. By using `fn()`, `fn` will be called with an empty `arguments` collection or no value passed for `this`.

`.apply(this, arguments)` calls `fn` or `old` and passes along the values for both from the current `function`.

```
var obj = {};

addMethod(obj, 'funcName', function (a, b) {
    console.log(this === obj);
    console.log(a, b);
    console.log(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
});

obj.funcName(2, 3);
// true
// 2, 3
// 2, 3
```

---

> Also, what exactly is happening when we return those functions, especially in the case of:
>
> ```
> return old.apply(this, arguments);
> ```

Well, the purpose of `addMethod` is to create a chain of functions where each knows about and can call the `old` function created before it.

For the example from the book, the chain is built as:

```
// after: addMethod(obj, 'funcName', function(){});
obj.funcName = function(){...} ──> function(){}
```

```
// after: addMethod(obj, 'funcName', function(a){});
obj.funcName = function(){...} ──────> function(a){}
               └── function(){...} ──> function(){}
```

```
// after: addMethod(obj, 'funcName', function(a,b){});
obj.funcName = function(){...} ──────────> function(a,b){}
               └── function(){...} ──────> function(a){}
                   └── function(){...} ──> function(){}
```

```
Legend:
  `└──` represents an `old` reference
  `──>` represents a `fn` reference
```

Each `function(){...}` is a unique instance created by reevaluating the same expression in a different scope/closure:

```
function(){
  if (fn.length == arguments.length)
     return fn.apply(this, arguments)
  else if (typeof old == 'function')
     return old.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Each `.apply()` then follows an "arm" or "arrow" to either an `old` or `fn` and the `return`s allow the result to be passed back through / in reverse.

Comment: Depending on `strict mode`, `Using fn() would call without arguments or a this value` is false. `this` would be `window` or `undefined` (see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) )

Comment: @xanatos It's not false, just incomplete. The value *passed* for `this` is `undefined`, though it may be replaced or *defaulted* to the global object. I was trying to focus on the passed values, though probably shouldn't have left that out.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer and comments.  I've tried this with five overloads in jsFiddle without using apply and can call the correct function each time using fn().  This is what confused my understanding.

Comment: @davy Using `fn()` will still call the expected function, but it won't pass any info about the original call to `ninja.test()` along to it. Since you're using `old.apply(...)` in the other part, those functions will pass that info along, which is why `console.log(argument)` looks right. But, try to log `a`, `b`, etc. inside the methods: http://jsfiddle.net/n89ec/. Then, try again with `.apply()`: http://jsfiddle.net/5KryU/

Comment: @Jonathan Finally the penny has dropped. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a breakdown of the code.

```
function addMethod(object, name, fn) {

   //get the old function from the object
   var old = object[name];

   //assign a new function to the property
   object[name] = function(){

      //See if the method signatures match, if they do execute the new method
      if (fn.length == arguments.length)

        /*
         Call the function provided using apply, the first argument "this" is the object
         it sets the context for this in the function we provide, second argument is
         the arguments provided to the function.  We must return the result of the 
         function.    

        */

         return fn.apply(this, arguments)

      //If the old property on the object is a function and the new functions signature
      //did not match call the old function assigned to the property.

      else if (typeof old == 'function')

         // Same as before calling with apply, setting context and returning result

         return old.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

It is important to understand how `apply` works.  It sets the context for `this` within a function.  For example:

```
var myFunction = function(){
   alert(this.msg);  //this will be set by what apply passes in as the first arg
};

var obj1 = {msg: "Hello"};
var obj2 = {msg: "World"};

myFunction.apply(obj1);
myFunction.apply(obj2);
```

**Example** http://jsfiddle.net/NCaKX/

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the point of `.apply`

I wont try to explain it :P you can find many good explanations, such as:

- [What is the difference between call and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply)
- [Why invoke "apply" instead of calling function directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936604/why-invoke-apply-instead-of-calling-function-directly)

tl;dr

`.apply` allows you set the `this` context. `.apply` allows you to pass arguments as an array, allowing for a variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript the `this` variable is not set in the moment of declaration of the function, but in the moment of execution, depending on which object was used to access the function reference.

You need to use `apply` not only because of the aforementioned dynamic bind of `this`, but also because you don't know how many arguments are there before hand; so `apply` receives a list of arguments and passes each element of the list as an individual argument to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.apply` the context can be specified

```
window.name = "window";

var object = {
    name:"object"
};

function showName(){
    alert(this.name);
}

showName(); // shows window
showName.apply(object); // shows object
```

more here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

```
fn.apply(this, arguments)
```

calls the `fn` with `this` as the current `this` and `arguments` as parameters.

```
fn()
```

calls the `fn` with `this` equal to `window` or `undefined` (depending if you are in "non strict mode" or in "strict mode") but *without* parameters.

In this [Mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) page there is a good discussion of `this` (always useful)